# how to call my object using addevent listner

Tags: javascript

```
obj = {
        click : function (msg ){
            alert(msg);
        }
    }
    var link = document.getElementById('link');
    link.addEventListener('click',obj.click,false);
```

The above code is working, but i need to pass the 'msg' in parameters how can i do? in case if i pass the parameter like this :

```
link.addEventListener('click',obj.click('message'),false);
```

then, it is calling the function, event without clicking on the link. for this how can i my object to only get call on the click as well with parameter in the function?

Any one help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an anonymous function as a callback:

```
   // Function to add event listener to t
   function load() { 
     var el = document.getElementById("t"); 
     el.addEventListener("click", function(){modifyText("four")}, false); 
   }
```

The example above was taken from the [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: Thanks, what is my target is, from my code i decided to make re-usable function. according to the link, that link will need to pass the parameter to obj, and i will make my pop-up sizes, accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, you give good information. now my functions works fine.